# Data binding in WPF using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a scenario where I would want to bind a string property to a text box on the UI when the string property changes.I would want to change the property in the code behind.Please find my work below :

```
XAML :

<Window x:Class="databinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:databinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding mobile1}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding mobile2}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,76,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Please find the MainWindow.xaml.cs below :

```
 namespace databinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            talk ta = new talk();
            ta.test();
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the class where I have defined my properties :

mobile.cs :

```
namespace databinding
{
   public class mobile:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       string mobile1model;
       string mobile2model;


       public string mobile1 { get { return mobile1model; } set { mobile1model = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("mobile1")); } }
       public string mobile2 { get { return mobile2model; } set { mobile2model = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("mobile2")); } }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, e);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

now I have a test class where I change the property value :

test.cs :

```
namespace databinding
{
   public class talk:MainWindow
    {

       public void test()
       {
         mobile mb = new mobile();
         mb.mobile1 = "This is mobile 1";
         mb.mobile2 = "This is mobile 2";

       }
    }
}
```

The problem statement here is that when I click the button1 the properties get updated but the textboxes on the UI does not get updated,also I am looking if the textboxes are updates as soon as the property changes or is it going to wait till the second property changes to get updated? Appreciate your support for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just go with MVVM and forget code behind. Your button click creates an new instance and sets the value. That object only exists in your event handler so couldn't be bound if you wanted to.

Comment: Can you suggest anexample or where can i get a proper example to achieve mvvm as i am new to wpf ?

Comment: Not really. But Google wpf MVVM tutorials and you'll find a few hundred thousand!

Answer (score 3):

Create one instance of `mobile` class, set it as `Window.DataContext` and call `test()` on that instance

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly mobile _mb = new mobile();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _mb;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        _mb.mobile1 = "This is mobile 1";
        _mb.mobile2 = "This is mobile 2";
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception when i try to build it ,please see below :private readonly talk _ta = new talk(); - >An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in databinding.exe

Comment: `talk` is a window and it cannot endlessly create itself as you'll end up with StackOverflowException. `mobile` is your view model class so it should be `private readonly mobile _mb = new mobile();` (refresh the page)

Comment: but textbox1 and textbox2 are updated at once,can we do something where as soon as the first property changes the ui needs to be updated,just like windows forms ?

Comment: UI is updated when `PropertyChanged` event is processed, when UI pulls new value from the view model. It's not updated when you change property value. You don't don't change UI property directly but bound view model property which only notifies UI to refresh its value

Comment: Can you please suggest what can be done in order to achieve what i am looking for ? as it is my primary requirement.Sincerely appreciate your support.

Comment: You can try updating it directly `textBox1.Text = "text";` but you will loose binding